# How to use ckeditor5 with livewire

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component  create.blade.php

```
<form>
    <label class="block font-bold mt-4" for="body">Description</label>
    <div  class=" my-5"  id="editor" name="body"></div>

    <input type="hidden" wire:model="body" id="bodyInput">

    <button wire:click.prevent="storePost()"  class="w-full bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-lg">Create</button>


</form>
```

my App.js i tried to catch the value here to pass it but doesn't work.

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ),
    {
        //add more headings
        heading: {
            options: [
                { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
                { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' },
                { model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Heading 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3' },
                { model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Heading 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4' },
                { model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Heading 5', class: 'ck-heading_heading5' },
                { model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Heading 6', class: 'ck-heading_heading6' }
            ]

        }
    }
)
.then( editor => {
    editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
        document.getElementById("bodyInput").value = editor.getData();
    });

})
.catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
} );
```

I try to dd my value in my CreatePost.php livewire model but i always get null. how can i pass the value to my livewire model? I know Ckeditor manipulates the DOM thats why i tried with a hidden field to catch it like this...

Answer (score 0):

In your then method, [emit a Livewire event](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events) with the input's value, and then capture that in your Livewire component.

```
.then( editor => {
    editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
        document.getElementById("bodyInput").value = editor.getData();
        // Livewire.emit('body-changed', editor.getData());
    });

})
```

// in Livewire component

```
protected $listeners = ['body-changed' => 'updateBodyFromListener'];

protected updateBodyFromListener($body)
{
    $this->body = $body;
}
```